# How to change order of data worksheet in table to match order of actions

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am new to using HP Unified Function Testing (version 12.00 Build 0511) and am having to update an existing test by inserting into it new actions.  When I inserted the new action I was only provided the option to add it to the bottom of the test.  Once the action was created I was able to easily move the action up between two previous actions according to the Test Flow.  But the associated worksheet in the Data table listing the parameters and values is still at the very end.  I like for the data worksheets associated with each action to have the same order.  That is, for the actions A, B and C listed in this order (top to bottom) in the Data Flow have associated data worksheets ordered as A, C, and B (left to right).  The worksheets should be A, B and C, just like that of the associated actions.

Does anybody know how to move the data worksheet forward or backward (left to right) among the other worksheets (similar to that of Excel)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to move datasheets backward or forward.If you are using Datasheet particular to your Actions suppose you have data under datasheet of Action B than you can simply use any particular Parameter of that Datasheet-'Action B' in your Action B.Or if you are using Global Datasheet than you can use it in any of the Actions in your test.

So the bottomline is that the order of the datasheets in your datatable doesnt effect your test.You have to just use your datatable according to your needs.

Comment: Let´s add that you can indeed control the order of sheets by opening the xls file directly with Excel, and editing the sheet order there. There is no technical reason to do so, though, that´s true.